# python ... working with numbers

Tags: python

I wanted to know if there is another command to make it shorter:

```
noes = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
```

this is the command I use so its has to do with years.

Comment: Things like this are covered in the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Reading this will save you a lot of time and trouble.

Answer (score 8):

`noes = map(str, range(1, 16))` assuming you really want strings. If not, then `noes = range(1, 16)` will suffice.

Answer (score 6):

If you're after a list of strings, you can use:

```
>>> x = [str(n) for n in range(1,16)] # or xrange if you wish
>>> x
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
```

A list of numbers can be made with either of the following:

```
x = [n for n in range(1,16)]
x = range(1,16)
```

Answer (score 1):

`noes = range(1, 16)`.

You can use `map(str, range(1, 16)` or `[str(i) for i in range(1, 16]` to get strings.

[range](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range).

[xrange](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) is similar to `range`, but doesn't make a list, but can be used in `for` loops, for example.

`[str(i) for i in xrange(1, 16)]`

Answer (score 0):

That's not numbers. You have quoted them, so they are strings. Numbers would be

```
noes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

And shorter would be

```
noes = range(1,16)
```

I'd recommend you to read a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
noes = range(1, 15);
```

Or, if you really need strings:

```
noes = [];
for i in range(1, 15):
  noes.append(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you then use this like

```
if AgeString in noes:
    print "U R 2 yng!"
```

It would probably be cleaner to do logical comparison, ie

```
if int(AgeStr) < 16:
    print "Too young"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
#creates a variable, that is easy to change
number = 15

#creates an empty list
noes = []

#add the numbers to the list using for loop
for x in range(1, number+1):
    noes.append(x)

#note that the first argument will be in the list, but the second will not be in the list at the range function
```